# How can I select the first 100 characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to truncate a column to a max of 100 characters. How do you do this in SQL Server?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT LEFT (your_column, 100) FROM your_table
```

Edit:

you can also try something like this:

```
  SELECT LEFT (your_column, LEN(your_column)-5) FROM your_table
```

for say if you want to trim the last 5 characters from a record.

Comment: Careful with the second approach, negative lengths return an error, not an empty string or `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks `Lucero` i didn't knew this... Matt might wanna keep that into account while implementing this approach...

Answer (score 18):

You can also use the [`LEFT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) function.

```
LEFT(col, 100)
```

Answer (score 8):

`SUBSTRING(myColumn, 1, 100)`

See the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Answer (score 3):

substring is the method:

```
SUBSTRING ( value_expression ,start_expression , length_expression )
```

from the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(COLUMN_NAME, 1, LENGTH) FROM TABLENAME where LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) > LENGTH
```

Ex:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(DESCRIPTION,1,100) FROM STOREDETAILS where LENGTH(DESCRIPTION)>100
```

For those records, with length less than 100, the actual value would be shown.

Otherwise, some databases induce blank characters in the resultant records.