# How do I limit the size of a text field?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, dapper

I am building my first MVC app, so please excuse me if its a rookie question. I am building a web app that queries an existing SQL database Log tables that are created when a new record is created, mapping the response back using Dapper.

However, the Log messages text can be 1000's of lines long. Is there a way that I can limit the length of the returned value to say 100 characters?

**EDIT #1**
I have tried the following after success in the SQL Server manager query:

```
   CAST(myColumn as CHAR(100)),
   LEFT(myColumn,100),
   SUBSTRING(myColumn,0,100)
```

All of these worked in the Server Manager Query window, but did not work when I put them in my ConnectionString.Query for Dapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright I found what was i was doing wrong. This is what i used to get the first 100 characters from the returned value:

```
   SELECT CAST(myColumn as CHAR(100)) AS mySHORTENEDColumn FROM myTable
```

I am kinda embarrassed that I didn't find it before posting the question but I figure maybe it will help someone else, that's a rookie like me.

Answer (score 3):

SELECT LEFT (your_column, 100) FROM your_table

Got the above answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280854/how-can-i-select-the-first-100-characters-in-sql-server) post...

Comment: I have also tried "CAST(myColumn,CHAR(100))" and "SUBSTRING(myColumn,0,100)" All returning null