# Fetch certain amount of character from database in Laravel Query

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.6

How to fetch certain amount of character from database using Laravel query ?

I have query like below

```
return $company->employee()->with('motorCycle', 'children')->get();
```

There is a column named `motorCycle.text` . I would like to fetch 500 character from that field.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know your table structure, and **pk and other columns** must specify yourself. See related sql query [How can I select the first 100 characters in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280854/how-can-i-select-the-first-100-characters-in-sql-server)

```
return $company->employee()
    ->with([
        'motorCycle' => function($query) {
            $query->select(DB::raw('LEFT (text, 500)'), 'pk and other columns');
        }, 
        'children'
    ])->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @Davit. I am trying to use your solution, I think it needs to fix comma `,` or braces `}`. Thanks

Comment: I fix  **;**. add in your question your table structure a I can fix it also

Comment: Thanks @Davit. Which table structure do yo need ? Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to use it like this `return $company->employee()->with([
        'motorCycle' => function($query) { $query->select(DB::raw('LEFT (text, 500)'), );
        }, 'children'])->get();`    

and I am getting error like below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjzrt.png

Comment: employee and motorCycle table

Comment: wrong code is **DB::raw('LEFT (text, 500)'),** last comma  **,**  corrected code is **return $company->employee()->with([ 'motorCycle' => function($query) { $query->select(DB::raw('LEFT (text, 500)') ); }, 'children'])->get();** but for get the relation model you also must be select **motorCycle primary key**